# All Possible combination with Main list containing sublists and without repeating the items in each subgroup

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

Using Python, I am looking for a solution to the following issue:

```
[['Orange', 'Banana'], ['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green'], ['Bike'], ['Ocean', 'Sky']]
```

The number of Items in each list in the result is 4

The combination has to result in all possible without repeating the members of each group in the same new sublist. All possible combinations should be:

```
[[Orange, Blue, Bike, Ocean],
[Banana, Blue, Bike, Ocean],        
[Orange, Yellow, Bike, Ocean],
[Banana, Yellow, Bike, Ocean],                           
[Orange, Green, Bike, Ocean],
[Banana, Green, Bike, Ocean],
[Orange, Blue, Bike, Sky],
[Banana, Blue, Bike, Sky],
[Orange, Yellow, Bike, Sky],
[Banana, Yellow, Bike, Sky],
[Orange, Green, Bike, Sky],
[Banana, Green, Bike, Sky]]
```

I am still trying to figure out how to sort it out. I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you're looking for `itertools.product`:

```py
import itertools as it

list_of_lists = [['Orange', 'Banana'], ['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green'], ['Bike'], ['Ocean', 'Sky']]

list(it.product(*list_of_lists))
# => [('Orange', 'Blue', 'Bike', 'Ocean'),
#    ('Orange', 'Blue', 'Bike', 'Sky'),
#    ('Orange', 'Yellow', 'Bike', 'Ocean'),
#    ('Orange', 'Yellow', 'Bike', 'Sky'),
#    ('Orange', 'Green', 'Bike', 'Ocean'),
#    ('Orange', 'Green', 'Bike', 'Sky'),
#    ('Banana', 'Blue', 'Bike', 'Ocean'),
#    ('Banana', 'Blue', 'Bike', 'Sky'),
#    ('Banana', 'Yellow', 'Bike', 'Ocean'),
#    ('Banana', 'Yellow', 'Bike', 'Sky'),
#    ('Banana', 'Green', 'Bike', 'Ocean'),
#    ('Banana', 'Green', 'Bike', 'Sky')]
```

Comment: Wow, I tried many things using itertools and didn't find the solutions, and you made it looks so easy, fantastic!!!! Worked perfectly.